# Argparse Python 3 аргументы меняющие режим работы программы

Tags: python, argparse

Мой скрипт на python имеет 2 режима работы, первый режим работы это загрузка файла, второй режим работы это отдача файла (выгрузка).

Скрипт принимает 3 аргументы, и 2 из них собственно определяют режим его работы.

Аргумент -L определяет ссылку на файл который надо загрузить (следовательно запускает режим загрузки).

Аргумент -F определяет имя файла который нужно будет отдавать (следовательно запускает режим выгрузки).

Помимо прочего, если режим работы - это выгрузка файла, скрипт должен принимать аргумент -P, который определит номер TCP порта, который будет открыт для выгрузки файла.
Собственно вопрос в том, как правильно парсить аргументы, чтобы если в аргументах есть аргумент -L, то мы не ждали больше никаких аргументов, а сразу запустили загрузку, а если же есть аргумент -F (или -P, их же не обязательно в одном порядке передавать), то мы ожидаем еще и аргумент -P, и запускаем выгрузку ?

Comment: А в чём сложность? Ну, проверяйте, выставлен ли такой-то аргумент и делайте то-то, какие проблемы? Где вообще ваш код, почему его нет в вопросе? Или вы сначала хотите всё выяснить, а потом писать код? В данном случае, если бы вы начали писать код вы бы, возможно, сами во всём разобрались бы и не нужно было бы никого спрашивать.

Comment: А в том сложность, что проверять выставлен ли такой-то аргумент, это значит делать лишние if-elif-else телодвижения, возможно есть способ сделать все проще, и да, я сперва максимально изучаю вопрос, потом уже что-то пишу, с моей точки зрения такой подход является наиболее правильным.

Comment: Да, кажется были какие-то продвинутые фреймворки для работы с аргументами, которые сами по набору аргументов делают какие-то действия. Но для начала и для работы с `argparse` достаточно будет обойтись парочкой обычных `if`-ов. Если хотите что-то лучше, то всё-равно приведите ваш код, как вы это сделали и тогда можете спросить: "А как сделать лучше/оптимальнее?" Сейчас просто выглядит так, что вы даже не попробовали сделать что-то сами, а уже просите совета. Тут так не принято.

Comment: Этот компьютер делает if-else - ему не трудно сделать это один раз. Если он будет делать это 1000раз в секунду, то тогда стоит задуматься , а сейчас то тьфу

Comment: @eri Дело не в беспокойстве о нецелевом расходовании ресурсов ЭВМ, дело в читаемости и красоте кода, если есть возможность обойтись без if-else, то лучше обойтись.
Один из вариантов обойтись без if-else - это использовать суб_парсеры, но они как я понял предполагают еще один аргумент командной строки, определяющий режим работы программы.
Если же использовать if-else, то оба аргумента (-F и -L) нужно делать required=True, но одного из них может и не быть, на что argparse выкатит просьбу таки указать один из обязательных (вероятнее всего совсем не нужных в конкретной ситуации) аргументов.

Comment: Так если мне память не изменяет, можно задать значения по умолчанию, скажем False и в консоле передавать только нужные аргументы ‍♀️

Comment: @Amgarak Так не изменяет, и при запуске такого скрипта без аргументов вообще, не будет выведено никакой help инфы, потому что ни один из аргументов не будет являться обязательным.

Answer (score 0):

Никаких if-ов.

```
import argparse


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
    cmd_a = subparsers.add_parser('cmd_a', description="Описание команды cmd_a")
    cmd_a.add_argument('name', type=str, help='Обязательный аргумент cmd_a')

    cmd_b = subparsers.add_parser('cmd_b', description="Описание команды cmd_b")
    cmd_b.add_argument('path', type=str, help='Обязательный аргумент cmd_b')
    cmd_b.add_argument('--noop', action='store_true', help='Опциональный флаг для cmd_b')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


command_map = {}


def command(name=None, **kwargs):

    def wrapped(fun):
        command_map[name or fun.__name__] = fun
        return fun

    return wrapped


@command(name="cmd_a")
def download(name, **kwargs):
    """Описание команды cmd_a"""
    print('downloading', name, kwargs)


@command(name="cmd_b")
def upload(path, noop=False, **kwargs):
    """Описание команды cmd_b"""
    print('downloading', path, noop, kwargs)


def main():
    parsed_args = parse_args()
    command_map[parsed_args.command](**dict(parsed_args._get_kwargs()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
$ ./arg_example.py --help

usage: arg_example.py [-h] {cmd_a,cmd_b} ...

positional arguments:
  {cmd_a,cmd_b}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
```

```
$ ./arg_example.py cmd_a --help 
usage: arg_example.py cmd_a [-h] name

Описание команды cmd_a

positional arguments:
  name        Обязательный аргумент cmd_a

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

```
$ ./arg_example.py cmd_a WoW 
downloading WoW {'command': 'cmd_a'}
```

```
$ ./arg_example.py cmd_b --help
usage: arg_example.py cmd_b [-h] [--noop] path

Описание команды cmd_b

positional arguments:
  path        Обязательный аргумент cmd_b

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --noop      Опциональный флаг для cmd_b
```

```
$ ./arg_example.py cmd_b 420
downloading 420 False {'command': 'cmd_b'}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваш пример, он работает, и я рассматривал использование саб_парсеров как один из вариантов решения проблемы, но мне не понравилось что для использования саб_парсера нужно будет использовать еще один аргумент командной строки.

Comment: С ифами можно сделать" скачать и сразу отдать"

Comment: так и без if-ов можно)